# Подкиньте идею к решению задачи Python

Tags: python

Подкиньте идею, функции, или код (в котором я буду разбираться! а не просто копировать). Всего неделю изучаю питон. прошу админов не закрывать вопрос. Ничего в голову не приходит.

Задача:

Дан список. Выведите те его элементы, которые встречаются в списке только один раз. Элементы нужно выводить в том порядке, в котором они встречаются в списке.

Sample Input 1:

1 2 2 3 3 3

Sample Output 1:

1

Sample Input 2:

4 3 5 2 5 1 3 5

Sample Output 2:

4 2 1

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ использовать класс Counter из модуля collections

> Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
> or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
> are stored as dictionary values.

```
from collections import Counter

array = [4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5]

count = [key for key, value in Counter(array).items() if value == 1]

# эквивалентно
count = []
for key, value in Counter(array).items():
    # key = элемент списка
    # value = кол-во повторений
    if value == 1:
        count.append(key)

print(count)
# [4, 2, 1]
```

В данном случае я пользуюсь тем, что в python3 список хранит порядок добавления элементов, поэтому результат сразу удовлетворяет условию "выводить в том порядке, в котором они встречаются"

Ок, Если нас хотят заставить забыть про стандартную библитеку, то можно использовать 2 списка, один для тех элементов, которые уже встречались

```
array = [4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5]

count = []  # список для элементов которые встречаются только 1 раз
filtered = [] # список элементов встречающихся больше

for a in array:  # итерируемся по элментам
    if a in count: # если элемент уже был добавлен в первый список
        filtered.append(a) # то он встречается больше 1-го раза
        count.remove(a) # удаляем из результата
    if a not in filtered:
        count.append(a) # есле элемента нет в отфильтрованных, то можно добавить

print(count)
# [4, 2, 1]
```

хорошо. нам не разрешают использовать дополнительный список

```
array = [4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5]

count = []

while len(array): # пока есть элементы
    a = array.pop(0) # берем первый и удаляем
    if a not in array: # если таких элементов больше нет
        count.append(a) # значит он не повторяется
    else: # а вот если есть
        while a in array: # пока элемент есть в списке
            array.remove(a)  # удаляем его

print(count)
```

Ну и последнее это использовать списоковый метод count()

```
array = [4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5]

count = []

for a in array:
    if array.count(a) == 1:
        count.append(a)

# тоже самое в одну строку. наверное это еще интереснее чем Counter
count = [x for x in array if array.count(x) == 1]

print(count)
# [4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Интереснее, однако работает за квадрат, а не nlog